# Lua Love2D Anim8. New sprite isn't showing, but the previous one was

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm currently making a 2D side-scrolled, and I have a pixel-artists help with this. I did my first animation with a random asset and it worked fine, but now that I'm doing it with the actual asset it stopped showing the asset(No errors). I have changed the resolution and frame size inside code.

```
function love.load()
    anim8 = require 'libraries/anim8-master/anim8'
    love.graphics.setDefaultFilter("nearest", "nearest")

    player = {};
    player.x = 100; --Players position on x axis
    player.y = 200; --Players position on y axis
    player.speed = 2; --Players speed
    player.spriteSheet = love.graphics.newImage('sprites/Man_Spite_Sheet_L.png'); --Players sprite-sheet imported
    player.grid = anim8.newGrid(32, 32, player.spriteSheet:getWidth(), player.spriteSheet:getHeight()); --Player spritesheet split into a grid
    
    player.animations = {}; --Table of players animations
    player.animations.left = anim8.newAnimation(player.grid('1-4', 3), 0.2); --Right animation
    player.animations.right = anim8.newAnimation(player.grid('1-4', 1), 0.2); --Left animation

    player.anim = player.animations.left
end

function love.update(dt)
    local isMoving = false;

    if love.keyboard.isDown("d") then --Move on keypress "d"
        player.x = player.x + player.speed;
        player.anim = player.animations.right;
        isMoving = true;
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("a") then --Move on keypress "a"
        player.x = player.x - player.speed;
        player.anim = player.animations.left;
        isMoving = true;
    end
    if isMoving == false then
        player.anim:gotoFrame(2)
    end

    player.anim:update(dt);

    --[[
    if love.keypressed("space") then
        player.y = player.y - 20;
        love.timer.sleep(1)
        player.y = player.y + 20;
    end
    --]]
end

function love.draw()
    player.anim:draw(player.spriteSheet, player.x, player.y, nil, 10);
end
```

Image of the output bellow:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since we dont know your Version of LÖVE and...
"Since anim8 uses LÖVE's graphical functions, and they change from version to version, you must choose the version of anim8 which is compatible with your LÖVE."
(https://love2d.org/wiki/anim8)
...i like to suggest that you download one of the Examples depending on your LÖVE Version...
https://love2d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=8281
...try it,...
[image]
...rename it to *.zip and unpack it to read/use the main.lua/anim8.lua.